# The negation of an implication statement

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

$$\neg(A \Rightarrow B)\lor \neg B$$

Does this this expression simplify to:?

$$\neg A\Rightarrow\neg B\lor \neg B$$

Which further simplifies to:

$$\neg A\Rightarrow\neg B$$

Comment: The first step to solving a math problem is to understand the question.  It sounds like you don't understand the question being asked.  How would you check if your solution is correct or not?

Answer (score 2):

Let us first look at the conditions 
under which $\lnot(A\implies B)\lor \lnot B$ is true.  Intuition is often better for $\land$ and $\lor$ than it is for $\implies$, so we eliminate the $\implies$.

The first term is equivalent to $\lnot(\lnot A\lor B)$, which is equivalent to $A\land \lnot B$.

And $(A\land \lnot B)\lor \lnot B$ is equivalent to $\lnot B$.

The second "formula" in the post is not a formula, since crucial parentheses are missing. But if we give precedence to $\implies$, it is 
not equivalent to $\lnot B$.

The formula $\lnot A\implies \lnot B$ is not equivalent to $\lnot B$, so it is not equivalent to $(A\land \lnot B)\lor \lnot B$.

Answer (score 0):

No. The negation of an implication is not the implication using the negations. $$\neg (X\implies Y) \not\equiv (\neg X \implies \neg Y)$$

It goes thus:

$$\begin{align}
(A \implies B)\implies B & \equiv
\neg (A\implies B) \lor B & \ni X\implies Y \equiv \neg X \lor Y
\\ &\equiv \neg(\neg A \lor B) \lor B & \text{again}
\\ & \equiv (A \land \neg B) \lor B & \text{DeMorgan's Laws}
\\ & \equiv (A \lor B) \land (\neg B\lor B) & \text{association}
\\ & \equiv (A \lor B) & \text{tautology}
\end{align}$$

Comment: i presume you mean the "DeMorgan law" instead of the "DeMoivre's law "(or are they really called DeMoivre's law where you live, that I would find very interesting))

Comment: Yes.  That does make more sense. @Willemien

Answer (score 0):

The negation of an implication always gives problems :)

Maybe the easiest way to understand it is that

$$ \lnot (  A \to B) $$

Means: "it is **definitly not** the case that A implies B"

and then think,

- I can only know that for sure that A does not imply B when A is true and B is false
- therefore

$$ \lnot ( A \to B) \to (A \land \lnot B) $$

I guess you probaby imagined that $$ \lnot ( A \to B) $$ means something like

- "we cannot proof that A implies B"

In technical terms this using is "not as failure" but then you are working with a very strange logic (closed world logic) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption )
and you better stay away from that.

Good luck